# Error in use of python multiprocessing module with generator function.

Tags: python, multiprocessing, generator, yield

Could some one explain what is wrong with below code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def sq(x):
    yield x**2
p = Pool(2)

n = p.map(sq, range(10))
```

I am getting following error

> MaybeEncodingError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         5 p = Pool(2)
>         6 
>   ----> 7 n = p.map(sq, range(10))
>
> /home/devil/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in
>   map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
>       258         in a list that is returned.
>       259         '''
>   --> 260         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
>       261 
>       262     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
>
> /home/devil/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in
>   get(self, timeout)
>       606             return self._value
>       607         else:
>   --> 608             raise self._value
>       609 
>       610     def _set(self, i, obj):
>
> MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[, ]'. Reason:
>   'TypeError("can't pickle generator objects",)'

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: how about changing yield to return?

Comment: I am trying to avoid storing of values.

Comment: yield would try to save the value and return will just return the value and forget it. nevertheless yield won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a *function* not a *generator* here. Means: change `yield` by `return` to convert `sq` to a function. `Pool` can't work with generators.

Moreover, when trying to create a working version on Windows, I had a strange repeating error message.

```
Attempt to start a new process before the current process
has finished its bootstrapping phase.

This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

literally quoting the comment I got, since it's self-explanatory:

> the error on windows is because each process spawns a new python process which interprets the python file etc. so everything outside the "if main block" is executed again"

so to be portable, you have to use `__name__=="__main__"` when running this module:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def sq(x):
    return x**2

if __name__=="__main__":
    p = Pool(2)
    n = p.map(sq, range(10))
    print(n)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Edit: if you don't want to store the values beforehand, you can use `imap`:

```
n = p.imap(sq, range(10))
```

`n` is now a generator object. To consume the values (and activate the actual processing), I force iteration through a list and I get the same result as above:

```
print(list(n))
```

Note that the documentation indicates that `imap` is much slower than `map`.

Comment: I am trying to avoid storing of values.

Comment: I tried "if __name__ == '__main__'" . It is the same error. 

I will wait for other people suggestions, else I will use "return" option.

Comment: the error on windows is because each process spawns a new python process which interprets the python file etc. so everything outside the "if main block" is executed again

Comment: @Manu: this version is correct, I would not suggest another version because Jean-François is right (like always ;-) )

Comment: @hansaplast no, not always :) But in that case I could test my answer and it worked, so...

Comment: @hansaplast. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think Manu meant they want to avoid storing a list of values to return in the worker function, which is why they wanted to use yield...

Comment: probably, but yield doesn't mix well with multiprocessing.

Comment: If he doesn't want to store a list but multiprocess.... What else can he do?